# Delphi. Set button position when form is created

Tags: winforms, button, position, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I have some code, it will be create form with button, but when form show button has wrong position.

```
var
  Form: TForm;
  Button: TButton;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(Self);
  try
    Button := TButton.Create(Form);
    Button.Parent := Form;
    Button.Left := 8;
    Button.Top := 8;
    Button.Height := 185;
    Button.Width := 292;
    Button.Anchors := [];
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form);
  end;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use HandleNeeded before create controls

```
Form.HandleNeeded
```

When form show - button has correct position

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear the `Anchors`.  That causes the button to move around when the Form is resized.  Leave the default `Anchors` set to `[akLeft,akTop]` so the button will honor your `Left`/`Top` values.

Comment: Then you are not managing your `Anchors` correctly. `akLeft` must be enabled for `Left` to work correctly, and `akTop` must be enabled for `Top` to work correctly.

Comment: Ok, let so I need set next property `Button.Anchors := [akBottom, akRight];`, but button has wrong position. When form create she have position (-8,-30).
But when I create and show form, then create button - button created in correct position

Comment: That is not what I said. Set `Button.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop];` instead, which is the default anyway. And then read up on what `Anchors` actually are and how they work.